# Download to excel - Service Stack

Tags: reactjs, servicestack

I have a servicestack doing download to excel as below

```
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: 'Get',
     async: true,
     data: data,
     success: function (data) {
        var blob = new Blob([dataTest], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
        var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        downloadLink.download = fileName;
        downloadLink.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
        },
    });
```

The data which comes to excel downloads in the first column as comma separated string.

I debugged to observe that the [data] in the code itself is passed as comma separated List and that is the reason it is downloading like that in excel. 
Something like:

```
[data] =
    Header1,Header2,Header3
    Data1,Data2,Data3
    Data4,Data5,Data6
```

If I replace the data by a table format the excel download happens correctly. 
Something like:

```
[data]=
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

There are two solutions I am thinking right now.

1. Convert this data into table and then use it for download.
2. Do download to excel in C# (service code)

Which is the best solution (maybe other than which I am thinking) to use in this scenario.

Comment: Any errors on console?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a more complete i.e. runnable example to the question. Ideally a stack snippet.